# Visual Studio 2017, a way to easily open an included script?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, razor

I'm sorry if this question has been asked before but I couldn't find an answer so far.

Let's say I have a asp.net mvc5 project, and I have included a external script file in my cshtml file using razor.

like so:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Path/File.js")"></script>
```

is there any way to easily open that file from the include statement? Or is there a different way to include the script that would allow such functionality?
plug-ins are also welcome.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: The JS files content will be included automatically when you set `src` to them. What you want to do with the script? You can call the function inside the script from Razor view page using function name.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough, but I just wanted a way to quickly go to the script file from the include statement. Eg: I click on the <script> tag and it opens up the script file in the src. It's just a navigation feature so I wouldn't have to search the file in the solution explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's such extension nor feature in Visual Studio unfortunately. There'are extension for Visual Studio Code (e.g. [Open file](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Fr43nk.seito-openfile)), but not for the "big" Visual Studio.

You can try to [create your own extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/starting-to-develop-visual-studio-extensions?view=vs-2017) to do that, it shouldn't be so complicated.

Or you can try to [create a feature request on UserVoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide) and wait if it's accepted and implemented.